how to convert string to integer or numeric using apache nifi processor UpdateRecord
So, my problem now is that I can't insert it into my database using the PutDatabaseRecord processor. It is reporting this error: "13:42:05 BRT ERROR
PutDatabaseRecord[id=fe4d0a37-0190-1000-7115-2eb52a682eef] Failed to put Records to database for FlowFile[filename=788b7747-61ed-4eb8-bbdc-7a26b0521352]. Routing to failure: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
".
My data comes as a string (in this format: "QTDEMBALAGEM" : "3", "VALIDITY DATE" : "2023-01-01 00:00:00.0",
"DTAFABRICACAO" : "2020-09-23 00:00:00.0").
Before inserting, my data goes through the UpdateRecord processor, where the obligation is to convert it to datetime. I use these commands to do this conversion: (toDate(/DTAFABRICACAO, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S')) and (toDate(/DTAVALIDADE, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. S')).
Unfortunately I don't know how to avoid this error and be able to insert it into the database.
enter image description here
enter image description here

Just a guess : Perhaps, the value has leading/trailing whitespaces and the conversion doesn't occur. Thus, can you retry with ${val:trim():toNumber()} ?

when you are saying "neither worked" - please provide more information how exactly it 's not working. is there an error?

So, my problem now is that I can't insert it into my database using the PutDatabaseRecord processor. It is reporting this error: "13:42:05 BRT ERROR PutDatabaseRecord[id=fe4d0a37-0190-1000-7115-2eb52a682eef] Failed to put Records to database for FlowFile[filename=788b7747-61ed-4eb8-bbdc-7a26b0521352].
